# Using given conditions to determine a variable $\alpha$ from a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I am given that at 1 am a snow plough has travelled 2 miles, but it takes until 3 am to travel a further one mile.

Also let $m$ be the distance travelled in miles by snow plough, $t$ be the time in (hours) where midnight is $t=0$, and $\lambda$ be a constant. The parameter $\alpha > 0$ is the number of hours before midnight at which the snow started to fall, i.e, snow started to fall at $t = -\alpha$.

I have solved my differential equation to obtain:
$$m = \lambda \ \mbox{ln}\left(\frac{t+\alpha}{\alpha} \right )$$

Therefore using the conditions above I obtain the following system of equations:

\begin{align*}
2 = \lambda \ \mbox{ln} \left (\frac{1+\alpha}{\alpha} \right ) \tag{1} \\ \\
3 = \lambda \ \mbox{ln} \left (\frac{3+\alpha}{\alpha} \right ) \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Now if I do 3/2 * (1) and set this equal to (2), and solve this for alpha, I obtain that $\alpha = 0.154700539$ hours. So converting to minutes I get $\alpha \cdot 60 = 9.282032340$ minutes.

Is this the correct value for $\alpha$ ?

Comment: $(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}-1)$ hours would look better to me.